# How to identify the make and model of disk and memory on a Linux server

Tags: linux, memory, hard-drive

Given a linux server (in my case Ubuntu) what's the easiest way to find out what make/model of harddisk and memory are being used?

i.e. what is the equivalent of ***/proc/cpuinfo*** for disk and memory?

Thanks.
J

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a lot of information about your system like this:

```
sudo lshw | less
```

To limit it to particular types of devices:

```
sudo lshw -class CLASS
```

Where "CLASS" might be "disk", "storage", "volume", "memory", etc. To see what classes are in use, do `sudo lshw -short`.

You can use this to show the vendor, model, serial number, size, etc. of your hard drives. I don't know of any way to show vendor and model of memory.

Comment: Try `dmidecode` may help for memory. Probably won't display vendor string, but you can lookup the ID.  `dmidecode -t 17`

Comment: wow, that really is useful!

Answer (score 0):

I think a more simple approach is to use the `hdparm` command, by typing `hdparm -i /dev/sda` for example.

Comment: Joel wants disk info and memory info